# Javascript: Trying to access form attributes with round brackets instead of square brackets works in IE

Tags: javascript

I hope I can explain this correctly ...

The following web page contains a form with an onSubmit handler. The onSubmit handler is a function that always returns `false`, meaning **the form should never be submitted**. But this only works in IE8 (and possibly in other versions of IE).

To get this to work in Firefox and Chrome I have to change the alert to:

```
alert(foo["firstName"].value);
```

I understand why using square brackets is the correct form, as the form is an associative array.

- But why is the form submitted in FF and Chrome (as `form("firstName")` is clearly wrong)?
- Is there an error I can catch?  (I couldn't see anything obvious in Firebug.)
- Is there a way to ensure the form is only submitted when `true` is returned?

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function alwaysReturnFalse() {
    alert(foo("firstName").value);
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="foo" onSubmit="return alwaysReturnFalse();">
    First name: <input name="firstName" type="text" value="Bob"/><br/>
    Last name: <input name="lastName" type="text"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
This form has an onSubmit handler that always returns false - meaning the form should never submit.<br/>
It works in IE8 - e.g. the onSubmit handler executes an alert() and then returns false.<br/>
It fails in Firefox and Chrome - e.g. the form is submitted.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form is submitted because the other browsers throw an error. The error causes the function to exit out early. The result, the code does not reach the return false so the form submits.

Comment: @REsmond The error is the `foo()`, the error message should be something like `TypeError: object is not a function`